# Destroy a building with an object

Tags: animation, particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation, vertex-groups

I have this building model and I want to have a sphere flying through the air destroy part of the building.  The building model I have is only a outside mesh with no interior.  I tried making a particle system on the building with the selected vertices that I wanted destroyed in a vertex group as the density.  Turned off physics and set start and end to 0 with a long lifetime.  Then I added explode with the same vertex group and the particle system.  Then I added a vertex weight proximity and set it to geometry with the sphere as target.  I then added a rigid body with the collider set to mesh.  On the sphere that flys through the top half of the building I added a rigid body set to animated.  The sphere moves through the building but nothing happens. How can I fix this or start a new method for doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Investigate the Explode modifier. A really simple way to sample it is to select the object to be destroyed and then choose Object > Quick Effects > Quick Explode.

Comment: The problem is that the whole building exploded when the sphere touches it, not the part where the sphere touches as it moves through the building.

Comment: show us your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=LbALRBaj" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/LbALRBaj/)

Comment: For some reason when I hit play the file crashes, I don't know why

Comment: Something like this perhaps?  It would need to be on a larger scale for a skyscraper/whatever.  Link to clip - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2TaYxgtg5HPV-KU?e=1qKD5R